# Zlib Z_STREAM_ERROR deflating data in Apache error_log

Tags: php, apache, zlib, deflate

Some subpages of my website don't get fully transmitted. Instead the stream just seems to stop. There are a couple of PHP warnings and messages that I think might be irrelevant (such as undefined variables and indexes). Then there is the following error in the error_log file:

```
[deflate:error] [pid 30608] [client 178.203.20.157:65337] AH01386: Zlib error -2 deflating data ((null)), referer: https://knipsakademie.de/mannheim
```

I found out that -2 means Z_STREAM_ERROR. But unfortunately I don't really understand what I am dealing with. The server is running Plesk 12.5.30 and PHP 5.6.22 as FPM.

phpinfo() tells me that zlib is enabled and that I have Stream Filters as follows: zlib.inflate, zlib.deflate and a Stream Wrapper setting named compress.zlib://

```
// this is not from php.ini but from the output of phpinfo()
zlib.output_compression = off
zlib.output_compression_level = -1
zlib.output_handler = [no value]
```

The strange thing is that this subpage works fine:

https://knipsakademie.de/frankfurt/gutschein

But this one gets the errors and isn't transmitted fully:

https://knipsakademie.de/mannheim/gutschein

The content on these two pages does differ but not the structure of the website itself. The content is pulled from a database. Now I do know that I generally have some kind of character set problem in this website because my JSON_encodes() only work with a workaround and I am kind of neglecting this problem since I don't fully understand how to address it. So I guess my question is: could this deflate issue have anything to do with character sets?

How can I get more information on this issue? Are there other server logfiles that I should look at?

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: All I can contribute is that a `Z_STREAM_ERROR` means that either the stream was not initialized, that is was corrupted after initialization, or that an attempt was made to use a closed stream. These all indicate some sort of logic or memory overwriting error in the application using zlib.

Comment: Thanks Mark. It seems like something was corrupted indeed. I have done a reinstall on a seperate webspace on the same server using all of the same settings (and of course same php files) and everything seems to work like a charm. Will switch that on to live in a couple of hours.

Comment: There is also a check (inside `inflateStateCheck`) that the pointer to the `z_stream` structure hasn't changed since initialization. I can be wrong but this way it's not self-contained so that you cannot easily push it into a C++ vector. Otherwise, the `Z_STREAM_ERROR` is returned. I guess something like `inflateCopy`/`deflateCopy` may be used to overcome this.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same:

```
AH01386: Zlib error -2 deflating data ((null))
(20014)Internal error (specific information not available): [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:39294] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (passing brigade to output filters)
```

after lots of:

```
PHP message: PHP Notice: Undefined index: _variablename_
```

this error came up only on some instances of my script (it extracts contacts information from a mysql database) but I was unable to find why.
At the end I decided to ignore PHP notices inserting:

```
<?php error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); ?>
```

on top of my php page
as described in:
https://www.stechies.com/undefined-index-error-php/

and the error disappeared

PHP Version 7.3 - Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)